# Can I call the same function inside of two other functions?

Tags: javascript

I have two different functions and I created a third function which I use to display some pieces of information. What I am trying to do is: I want to display **photographerPrice** which is inside of the **photographerProfil** function and the **sum** of all the likes which is inside of the **photographerWork**  function, those two elements I want to display inside my third function **likesAndPrice**.
I tried to call the function **likesAndPrice** inside two of the functions **photographerProfil** and **photographerWork** using two arguments and two parameters: it doesn't work, it only works when I use one single parameter either for likes or the price but not both. How can I display the two of them Price and Likes in one place ?

The result I want: [image: photo]

**photographerProfil** Function code

```js
function photographerProfil(JsonData){
  const id = window.location.search.split('id=')[1];  
  const photographers = !id ? JsonData.photographers : JsonData.photographers.filter(photographer => photographer.id == id);

  photographers.forEach(element => {
    const domDiv = document.getElementById('photographer-container');
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    const photographerPrice = element.price;
    const profilTemplate = `
      <div class="profil-container">
        <h2>${element.name}</h2>
        <p>${element.city}, ${element.country}</p>
        <p class="tagline">${element.tagline}</p>
        <p>${element.tags.map(tag => `<button class='tags'>#${tag}</button>`).join(" ")}</p>
        <button id="test">Contactez-moi</button>
        <div class="photoBox">
            <img src="${element.portrait}" alt="photo">
        </div>
      </div>
    `
    newDiv.innerHTML = profilTemplate;
    domDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    showModal();                         // function invoked here 
    photographerWork(JsonData, element)  // function invoked here 
  }) 
}
```

**photographerWork** Function code

```js
function photographerWork(JsonData, homeElement){
    let sum = 0;
    const homeElt = homeElement.id;
    JsonData.media.forEach(element => {   
    if(homeElt == element.photographerId){
        const domDiv = document.getElementById('photographer-work');
        const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        sum += element.likes;
        const workTemplate = `         
            <div class="photo-box"> 
                <div class="photo">
                    ${videoOrImage(element.image, element.video, element)}
                </div>   
                <div class="text">
                    <p> ${element.tags}<b>${element.price} €  &nbsp ${element.likes} <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        newDiv.innerHTML = workTemplate;
        domDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
      }
  })
  likesAndPrice(sum) // function invoked here  
}
```

And the Function in which I want to display the Likes and Price

```js
//total likes and price
function likesAndPrice(sum){
  const domDiv = document.getElementById('photographer-work');
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const likesAndPriceTemplate = `
  <span>${sum} <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></span>
  <span></span>  
  `
    newDiv.classList.add('likesAndPriceContainer')
    newDiv.innerHTML = likesAndPriceTemplate;
    domDiv.appendChild(newDiv)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can also call `likesAndPrice()` in your `photographerProfil` function

Inside `photographerWork` at the last line you can return the local sum variable

```
return sum;
```

Now when you invoke the function at `photographerProfil` it returns the sum

```
let sum = photographerWork(JsonData, element)  // function invoked here
```

Now you have your *sum* and the *photographerPrice* both in your photographerprofil function available this means you can call here the likesAndPrice function.

```
likesAndPrice(sum, photographerPrice) // function invoked here
```

*Note:* you have to update the signature where you define the function likeAndPrice() and add another parameter to it

```
function likesAndPrice(sum, <param>){
```